# PyWin32 issue after coverting pyhon script to exe using PyInstaller

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pyinstaller, pywin32

I wrote a python script that collects Windows Events and it works fine when I run the script, however I'm using PyInstaller to covert my script to an exe. PyInstaller successfully coverts the script to exe but when running the exe that PyInstaller created, the 'SystemTime' in Win32EvtLog field is 'None'.

I added a print statement to see what were the values I was getting back from `EvtRender()`.
**Running Script(python main.py) results:**

```
[('Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing', 1), (IID('{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}'), 15), (4656, 6), (None, 0), (0, 4), (12800, 6), (0, 4), ('0x8020000000000000', 21), (pywintypes.datetime(2023, 8, 31, 0, 3, 11, 489000, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), 17), (451643143, 10), (None, 0), (None, 0), (4, 8), (30892, 8), ('Security', 1), ('DESKTOP-XXXXXXX', 1), (None, 0), (1, 4)]
```

**Running exe:**

```
[('Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing', 1), (IID('{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}'), 15), (4656, 6), (None, 0), (0, 4), (12800, 6), (0, 4), ('0x8020000000000000', 21), None, (451212341, 10), (None, 0), (None, 0), (4, 8), (26820, 8), ('Security', 1), ('DESKTOP-XXXXXXX', 1), (None, 0), (1, 4)]
```

Not sure if there special way in building exe for python script that uses windows DLL but from looking at the results I'm assuming something is going wrong with pywintypes.datetime() when building the exe.

Things I tried:

- Copy pythonsevice.exe from 'venv/Lib/site-packages/win32/' to the '/dist/' folder like mention in [Running as a Window Service](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)
- Add pywintypes as a hidden-import.

Lastly everything I have done has been run with admin privileges.